# Check if "Remove permissions if app is unused" is disabled for a particular app

Tags: android

How can I programmatically determine whether the "Remove permissions if app is unused" setting is enabled or disabled for a particular app?

Answer (score 3):

You can check whether the user has enabled or not, and you can also request them to disable it.

Check if the user has it enabled:

```
val future: ListenableFuture<Int> =
    PackageManagerCompat.getUnusedAppRestrictionsStatus(context)
future.addListener(
  { onResult(future.get()) },
   ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(context)
)

fun onResult(appRestrictionsStatus: Int) {
  when (appRestrictionsStatus) {
    // Status could not be fetched. Check logs for details.
    ERROR -> { }

    // Restrictions do not apply to your app on this device.
    FEATURE_NOT_AVAILABLE -> { }
    // Restrictions have been disabled by the user for your app.
    DISABLED -> { }

    // If the user doesn't start your app for months, its permissions 
    // will be revoked and/or it will be hibernated. 
    // See the API_* constants for details.
    API_30_BACKPORT, API_30, API_31 -> 
      handleRestrictions(appRestrictionsStatus)
  }
}
```

ask to disable it:

```
fun handleRestrictions(appRestrictionsStatus: Int) {
  // If your app works primarily in the background, you can ask the user
  // to disable these restrictions. Check if you have already asked the
  // user to disable these restrictions. If not, you can show a message to 
  // the user explaining why permission auto-reset and Hibernation should be 
  // disabled. Tell them that they will now be redirected to a page where 
  // they can disable these features.

  Intent intent = IntentCompat.createManageUnusedAppRestrictionsIntent
    (context, packageName)

  // Must use startActivityForResult(), not startActivity(), even if 
  // you don't use the result code returned in onActivityResult().
  startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE)
}
```

Source: https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2021/09/making-permissions-auto-reset-available.html

Comment: This is really, really close to what I need. I'm looking for checking the setting on apps other than my own.

Comment: It looks like this might not be possible: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager#isAutoRevokeWhitelisted(java.lang.String)

Comment: I don't seen an APIO for this except that one above for Android 11 (R). But even that doesn't seem to work with `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WHITELIST_AUTO_REVOKE_PERMISSIONS" />`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a great question and I'm still trying to determine what that even means.

It appears on my Bixby app that came installed on my Samsung. It goes off at random at least 4 times an hour.

I've disabled it many times and I feel "remove permissions if app is unused" is worded in such a confusing way intentionally with the intention to be invasive.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It's not clear to me whether the Bixby routine is using Play Protect under the hood or not. It's unclear to me what the App Info is showing me.